# How do I align "Read more" to the right?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using ReadMore.js on my website, it is a plugin that creates a "readmore/close" button that toggles the visibility of content.

Currently the 'read more' button is aligned to the left under the article it collapses. An example of this code is on http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/. I would like the button to align to the right.

I have looked through the documentation, there doesn't seem to be any configuration that allows me to change the alignment. The code that is produced by  the script doesn't have a class attached:

```
<a href="#" data-readmore-toggle="rmjs-1" aria-controls="rmjs-1">Read More</a>
```

Is there a way of creating a class that targets the 'data-readmore-toggle'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way:

```
[data-readmore-toggle^="rmjs"] {
    text-align: right;
}
```

This targets all the datatypes that begin with `rmjs`.

Answer (score 1):

`article + [data-readmore-toggle] {
    text-align: right;
}`

OR

```
[data-readmore-toggle] {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix

```
a.article.atn {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Or

```
a{
text-align:right
}
```